# maintenance.flag file usage

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

When I first started using Magento and I first made a backup, I ticked the "put website into maintenance mode" button. Once this was done when I tried to visit my site I was given a 503 error (I think). I found that this was due to Magento creating a `maintenance.flag` file.

I've come to understand that this is used to stop people accessing your site when you are updating things or backing up.

Is it possible to use a `maintenance.flag` file to block people from visiting your site while you're physically updating and checking? I have 2 servers a test and a live server. The live server uses SSL and is much faster than the free testing server that I have. Currently I'm developing changes on the test server and then uploading to the live server once I know it al works and looks OK.

Since we applied the SSL to the live server. Certain things are (or are not) happening when I do updates. I'm wondering if I can temporarily block access to my site while I check my updates then allow people back on.

The `maintenance.flag` file blocks me out of my site as well so as far as I can understand what I want to do is not possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to set Maintenance Flag and then have your `index.php` check for a set of addresses that are let through while serving everyone else a 503 page. Only those systems will be allowed admin and public access while maintenance.flag is set. Find the section in `index.php` and make some modifications. I use the following on Magento 1.4.2.0, check to make sure 1.7 uses the same mechanism in `index.php`:

```
$maintenanceFile = 'maintenance.flag';
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

/***************
 * IP's allowed in maintenance.
 * Use publicly visible IP addresses on LIVE, local if on DEV
 ***************/

$allowed = array('10.0.0.100','10.0.0.101','10.0.0.20');

if (file_exists($maintenanceFile) && !in_array($ip, $allowed)) {
    $basePath = dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/errors/503.php';
    exit;
}
```

Comment: +1 for this solution. Modules are nice and all, but for something as simple as just adding some simple changes to index.php, a module seems a little overkill.

Comment: Thanks! Magento modules can be like taking prescription drugs. After taking three in combination, you need a fourth to counteract the adverse interactions. Next thing you've got seven with two or three to attempt fixing what the remainder are doing to you. I've got two module rewrites going in at the moment where I've got to combine two classes to take care of three modules that got into a dirty knife fight.

Comment: If modules are not used but core files are modified then these changes will be lost with upgrades.

Comment: It's really easy to make a backup of index.php, only one file involved in the process so its an NBD. It's not really in the same bailiwick as core file modification. If it gets replaced during maintenance, the maintenance.flag file is still active with the new index.php, so you merely diff and replace when you find you no longer have admin access.

Comment: I agree to this that its just one index.php file that can be easily modified.But if developer breaks some standards once then He might follow the same on other places so better stick to standards and installing a module is not a complex task.

Comment: Yep, I know, we hired one once, it's why we write our own modules now.

Answer (score 3):

Store Maintenance  : http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/store-maintenance.html

This extension will take care of your needs.

Comment: +1 on this recommendation.  It also allows you to insert your IP address in the Configuration > Developers section so you can bypass the page.

Comment: +1 Dealing with a user that installed two of the inferior competitor's store maintenance modules. I can vouch that this is a far better store maintenance module.